# Sentiment Analysis Model - handle negation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am building a Sentiment Analysis model using NLTK and SKlearn. The accuracy of the model is quite good ca. 75%. Model is trained on 7500 labelled short movie reviews and tested on 3000 labelled short movie reviews.

However I have noticed it doesn't recognise the Negation (e.g. I am not happy, I am not very well - the model scores them as "positive"). I think I have to use some Bi-grams NLTK function but I am not too sure how to add in the current code.

Below part of the code where I define the features

```
# open and read txt file with labelled dataset
short_pos = open("short_reviews_positive.txt","r").read()
short_neg = open("short_reviews_negative.txt","r").read()


all_words = []
documents = []


# tokinize and tag and allow only "adjective" "J"
allowed_word_types = ["J"]

for p in short_pos.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (p, "pos") )
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_word_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())


for p in short_neg.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (p, "neg") )
    words = word_tokenize(p)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for w in pos:
        if w[1][0] in allowed_word_types:
            all_words.append(w[0].lower())

# define features
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
word_features = [w for (w, c) in all_words.most_common(5000)]


def find_features(document):
    words = word_tokenize(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features



featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

random.shuffle(featuresets)


training_set = featuresets[:7500]
testing_set =  featuresets[7500:]
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient negation examples in your training set?  If so, the model should be able to extract the combination of "not" and an adjective to properly toggle the classification of each statement.  Bi-grams are not a general solution: negation is usually an adverb, which can appear in a variety of locations.  For instance, the software will not recognize "not well" in your example of "I'm not very well".  Even worse is something such as "I should be happy with this situation, but I am not."  Finding "not happy" in this sentence is hardly straightforward.

Comment: You can run an algorithm that adds a prefix or suffix to any word following negation such as *not*. Thus, *I am not happy* --> *I am not happy_not*. At the same time, *I am happy* remains unchanged. When you read in the text afterward, *happy* and *happy_not* will be treated as two completely different words. You can of course experiment with the window length for the suffixation.

Comment: This model is not lexicon based but is ML based. Therefore suppose not to treat the text as "bag-of-words". On the contrary it suppose to take into account any relations between the words in the text. Now the  vector of the most common features is formed only by adjective, not sure if I have to add also adverb and verb, (Ex ['is', "'s", "n't", 'be', 'not', 'are', 'has', 'more', 'have'..]) in order to pick up better the negation

Comment: In the training set there are a few sentences with negation. However the model acting funny. If I test the model on an exact sentence from the training set (ex "it's not very interesting") I got a negative classification, as I expected. Unfortunately if I test for "there's something interesting in playing football" I still got negative classification. At the moment the vector is formed only by Unigrams, not sure if adding N-grams (ex "not ideal") it can improve spotting the notation.

Comment: If I use the happy_not system, I have to add all this _not bigrams to the training set? How I cam make sure that happy_not will be treated in different way?

Comment: Another approach could look whether a negation appears in the sentence and inverts the positive/negative scores of the adjectives, adverbs etc. But  I am not sure how to implement this efficiently

Comment: any suggestions on my questions above?